# Auto create folders using Excel field entries

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, macros, worksheet-function

I need to generate folders containing certain Excel field entries:

[image]

Additionally, I need to append a date to the folder name based on that entry

So If I have the above Excel table, I'd need the following set of folders to be generated in the same directory:

[image]

Is this possible using a macro?  Also, in case I ***add another entry*** how would I generate another folder ***only for that entry***; for example I add another project CWO-1106:

[image]

Basically, I'd like to keep updating the Excel sheet and *create folders only for the new entries*

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to add subfolders containing the Project-ID? Ex: CWO-1101_QUOTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the macro.

- Make sure the spreadsheet with the Project ID and Start dates is in view (selected) before you run the macro.
- Set the folder where you want to create these folders in ParentFolderPath

  ```
  Sub CreateFolders()

  'Variable definations
  Dim FolderListRange As Range
  Dim FolderRange As Variant
  Dim FolderName As String
  Dim ParentFolderPath As String

  On Error GoTo Handle
      ' Set the Folder where the individual folders should be created
      ParentFolderPath = "Folders"

      Set FolderListRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A64000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

      For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange
          If FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Continue

          FolderName = ParentFolderPath & "\" & FolderRange.Value & "-" & Format(FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

          If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
              FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
          End If

  Continue:
      Next

  Handle:
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Nicely done, Lee. Just needs the additional hyphen between the project-ID the date.