# Auto create folders using Excel field entries (using a template folder)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I need to generate folders for new job numbers that are generated in excel.

Every time the excel sheet is updated with a new job number I need to generate a folder in a set location with the folder name being the job number from the excel sheet

I have found and used

[Auto create folders using Excel field entries](https://superuser.com/questions/444014/auto-create-folders-using-excel-field-entries)

```
Sub CreateFolders()

'Variable definations
Dim FolderListRange As Range
Dim FolderRange As Variant
Dim FolderName As String
Dim ParentFolderPath As String

On Error GoTo Handle
' Set the Folder where the individual folders should be created
ParentFolderPath = "Folders"

Set FolderListRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A64000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each FolderRange In FolderListRange
    If FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then GoTo Continue

    FolderName = ParentFolderPath & "\" & FolderRange.Value & "-" & Format(FolderRange.Offset(0, 1).Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")

    If FileSystem.Dir(FolderName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        FileSystem.MkDir FolderName
    End If

Continue:
    Next

Handle:
End Sub
```

This works however I want to know is it possible to create the new folder using a template folder?

The new job folder contains a load of sub folders that need to be in there.

Comment: Are the sub folders always named the same within the job folder? Or are they specific to the job number too?

Comment: They are always the same, and are not specific. basically a new quote is created in the excel sheet and given a number, from this i have a template folder containing all the sub folders that i copy and rename with the newly generated number, apologies for the long delay in my reply

Comment: the sub-folders are always the same and come from a template folder I keep, every time I create a new job number I copy and paste a template folder containing all of the sub folders and rename it with the newly generated job number

Comment: Take a look at this article. It has some great VBA examples of how to [Copy and Move files and folders](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm).